# Can you request your personal data from a government agency under GDPR?

Tags: gdpr

Can you address a request to a government agency (let's say for example the French "Ministry of education") to access the data they store about you under GDPR ?

Does GDPR requirements apply to states or is it only regulating personal data usage of private companies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDPR and domestic French legislation applies to data held by the state (with some exceptions)

Most French government sites seem to place the information consistently at the bottom of the page under **Personal Data and Cookies** (*Données personnelles et cookies*). For the [Ministry of Education](https://www.education.gouv.fr/cid135661/donnees-personnelles-cookies.html):

> Vous pouvez accéder aux données vous concernant et exercer vos droits
>   d'accès, de rectification, de limitation, d'opposition que vous tenez
>   des articles 15, 16, 18 et 21 du RGPD, par courriel auprès de la
>   délégation à la communication via le formulaire "À propos du site".
>
> You can access the data concerning you and exercise your rights of
>   access, rectification, limitation, opposition that you hold articles
>   15, 16, 18 and 21 of the RGPD, by email with the delegation to the
>   communication via the "About the site" form.

Comment: That's brilliant ! I really thought it didn't apply to them. Thanks a lot !